# Installing Allegro in Dev-C++ using their Packages

Tags: c++, dev-c++, allegro

I'm trying to install Allegro in Dev-C++, and rather than do it manually, I noticed the new version was in the available packages, so that'd be easier.

[Here it is](https://i.imgur.com/hXzkp.png) in the manager.

[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1JGq.png) showing itself containing the header file.

And when I try to run the simplest of Allegro programs, [it doesn't recognize it](https://i.imgur.com/nhnXY.png).

Anyone know how to fix this? Or a better way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your project to reference the correct libraries. MinGW does not support auto-linking, so you'll need to configure DevCPP's project file to point MinGW at the right location.

Comment: @Befall: No idea. I've not used DevCPP in a long time because it's bundled with an ancient copy of MinGW and is no longer maintained.

Comment: Figured it out, I just had to create a project that was made for Allegro, works fine. Thanks!